# can't connect to tomcat/telnet to a remote host

Tags: networking, linux-networking, port

I want to connect to a tomcat installed on a VM which is running on my laptop however I am not able to connect to it.

- I stopped the IPTables to ensure that this is not a firewall issue.
- I can ping to that machine.
- I can access the Internet from my VM.
- I can do a SSH to my VM

Below is the output from my NMAP command run from my laptop which shows that I can only access ssh port for my VM

```
>nmap.exe -A 192.168.158.131

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-28 17:29 India Standard Time
Nmap scan report for 192.168.158.131
Host is up (0.00030s latency).
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 5.3 (protocol 2.0)
| ssh-hostkey:
|   1024 b4:b1:e4:d4:73:f7:16:95:8f:2a:5e:df:ea:f3:82:da (DSA)
|_  2048 4e:e9:f2:8c:eb:3c:ca:38:9d:3a:6f:d6:35:48:13:1e (RSA)
MAC Address: 00:0C:29:D7:C5:BA (VMware)
Warning: OSScan results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open and 1 closed port
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 2.6.X|3.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
OS details: Linux 2.6.32 - 3.10, Linux 2.6.32 - 3.13
Network Distance: 1 hop

TRACEROUTE
HOP RTT     ADDRESS
1   0.29 ms 192.168.158.131

OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.37 seconds
```

I also ran the netstat -tuplen command from my VM which clearly says that the Tomcat port 8086 is available for external access.

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          13838      2288/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          13324      2180/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          14435      2646/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      495        14221      2529/mysqld
tcp        0      0 :::8086                     :::*                        LISTEN      500        43936      5923/java
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      0          13845      2288/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:631                     :::*                        LISTEN      0          13323      2180/cupsd
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      0          14437      2646/master
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:8005       :::*                        LISTEN      500        44062      5923/java
tcp        0      0 :::8009                     :::*                        LISTEN      500        43937      5923/java
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               0          32209      5546/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631                 0.0.0.0:*                               0          13332      2180/cupsd
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you turned off IPTables on the guest OS (your VM) and not on the host OS? Also, your nmap scan did not include port 8086, so is inconclusive. Check out the -p argument in the documentation.

Comment: @JasonAzze  : Thanks. My IPTABLES were not shutdown correctly. They need to be turned off by doing a sudo. Somehow they didn't give an error when I turned them off as a normal user.

Comment: is selinux in enforcing mode? then it could be that your port isnt labeled correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced same issue before few days so I checked listening ports using netstat utility and I found tomcat port bind with IPv6 instead of IPv4.

Then I've added below line in catalina.sh in order to bind tomcat ports on IPv4.

```
JAVA_OPTS= $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses
```

And my issue got solved with this. Hopefully this solution also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

My IPTABLES were not shutdown correctly. They need to be turned off by doing a sudo. Somehow they didn't give an error when I turned them off as a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and tried the answer suggested by @Vaibhav Panmand, but it didnt solve my issue. To bind my tomcat to IPv4 instead of IPv6, I edited the /etc/sysctl.conf with following config changes:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

After saving this file, I did the "sudo sysctl -p" command and restarted tomcat. And voila! My tomcat is using IPv4 instead of IPv6. I hope this helps whoever lands in a similar fix as I did.